# java Swing JTable change cell Border

Tags: java, swing, jtable, border

I would like to create a JTable that can change the border color of the outer highlighted cells on the press of a Button.

I already found out how to make the button and get the information for the cells that have to be changed like this:

```
        frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Create Border "){ 

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private void createBorder(){
            System.out.println(table.getSelectedColumn());
            System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow());
            System.out.println(table.getSelectedRowCount());
            System.out.println(table.getSelectedColumnCount());
            System.out.println(table.getSelectedRows()[0]);
            System.out.println(table.getSelectedColumns());             

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            createBorder();
        }

    }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocation(150,150);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

what's left now is to somehow get the individual cells and change their border.

So far i only found solutions for changing the border at the creation of the table through the renderer.

Comment: *"i only found solutions for changing the border at the creation of the table through the renderer."* The renderer can change the way it renders cells according to not only the row, column, value, **selection**, focus etc., but the value of any attributes that it has access to. So if the renderer is declared as an inner class of `GUI` and said `GUI` has a boolean attribute (e.g. `makeBigBorder`), the renderer can change the rendering based on whether `makeBigBorder` is true or false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i only found solutions for changing the border at the creation of the table through the renderer.

Another approach might be to overriding the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of the `JTable`, so you don't need to create a custom renderer for each type of data.

Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for some examples of this approach. One example shows how to place a border around the entire row instead of each cell.